# Вычислить из всех чисел высшее и наименьшее

Tags: php, delphi, lazarus

Надо в EDIT вписать любое количество чисел и с помощью кнопки определить самую большую цифру и маленькую

Comment: Интересный способ "при помощи кнопки" определения самую большую цифру. Как найдете напишите

Answer (score 3):

Разделите входную строку на части, например, с помощью `TStringList.CommaText`

Преобразуйте каждую строку из получившегося списка в число с помощью `StrToInt`

Значение первого присваивают максимуму и минимуму, а потом с ними сравнивают остальные числа

Comment: Скорее следует сравнить числа между собой и найти макс и мин, а не с какими-то заранее данными эталонами. Если я, конечно, правильно понял вопрос.